# Amazon SNS : MessageAttributes TTL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

We are using Amazon SNS for our push notification service. It used to work fine, until I've thought to include a TTL - in MessageAttributes. Basically For testing purpose I want to keep the TTL Time as 60 seconds.

I use RestClient. I donot use Amazon SDK.

```
def publish(endpoint_arn, message,message_attribute)
    params = {
            :TargetArn => endpoint_arn,
            :Message => JSON.dump(message),
            :MessageStructure => 'json',
            :MessageAttributes => {
                message_attribute => {
                    :DataType => 'String',
                    :StringValue => '60'
                }
            }
        }
     post(:Publish, params)
end
```

message_attribute is a string that contains, 'AWS.SNS.MOBILE.GCM.TTL'

```
def post(command, params)
    params.merge!(default_post_params(command))
    params[:Signature] = calculate_signature(params, 'POST')
    response = RestClient.post(SNS_URL, params)
end
```

Whats wrong in the code above, Amazon document says what i've done is correct.

Amazon SDK API Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-ttl.html

PS: default_post_params, would have a generalised post params, like Access Key, SNS Url. And it  works fine. Only after including MessageAttributes key it says,

```
<Error>
  <Type>Sender</Type>
  <Code>MalformedQueryString</Code>
  <Message>Keys may not contain [</Message>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is coming due to lack of dictionary key and value.

In message attribute there is two key

```
1.DataType
2.StringValue
```

Create a dictionary and add these two keys in dictionary with there value.

Definitely it will work.